# Google transliterate API problem in Firefox

Tags: api, firefox, transliteration

I am trying to use Google Transliterate API helloWorld in Firefox 4.0.1 and WindowsXP

I am using node.js 0.4.7 to serve the page

When I load the page through node.js, i get the following error: "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope"

The page is rendered successfully if I double-click it and open in Firefox from disk, or if I open it in IE8, Opera or Chrome

Any idea why this happens and what is the way around it? Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?api-key-here">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Google Transliterate API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
                [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.URDU],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Type in Urdu (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Urdu)<br>
    <textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be aware that the Transliterate API is deprecated and will unfortunately be [shut down](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html).

Comment: apparently its an FF bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635548 - but I wish there were a workaround